# Is this property of continuous functions equivalent to anything familiar? If not, does it at least have a name?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

If I understand correctly, every morphism of topological spaces $f : Y \leftarrow X$ factorizes uniquely into a composite of three morphisms $$f = c \circ b \circ a$$

such that $c : Y \leftarrow \mathrm{img}(f)$ is an embedding, $b : \mathrm{img}(f) \leftarrow \mathrm{coimg}(f)$ is a continuous bijection, and $a : \mathrm{coimg}(f) \leftarrow X$ is a quotient mapping. Furthermore, $f$ is injective iff $a$ is an isomorphism, and surjective iff $c$ is an isomorphism. So let us say that $f$ satisfies the *foo condition* iff $b$ is an isomorphism.

> **Question.** Is the foo condition equivalent to anything more familiar?
>
> If not, does this condition at least have a name, either from general topology, or from the category theory of ternary factorization systems?

Comment: I.e., The foo condition is that the map $Y \to X/\sim\ :\ y \mapsto f^{-1}(y)$ is continuous, where $x \sim z$ when $f(x) = f(z)$.

Comment: I do not expect anything else. Just ask yourself: Given a continuous bijection $b: A\to B$, what is simpler than just saying that $b$ is a homeomorphism (or has continuous inverse)? Under extra conditions, this is equivalent  to the requirement that $b$ is proper (which is sometimes easier to verify).

Comment: The result you start with, by the way, is the [(epi, strong mono) factorization system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(epi,+mono)+factorization+system) on **Top**.